# Update table A timestamp when table B timestamp updates? (mysql)

Tags: mysql

Been reading many other questions along the same sort of lines but can't for the life of me find the solution that I'm looking for.

I have two tables, A and B we will call them. Both tables have a column called last_update that is a timestamp and set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

So when either table is updated the last_update column contains the current timestamp.

What I would like is when table B has been updated table A's last_update column should also be updated to the current timestamp.

Is there a way to go about this when setting up the tables so that it automatically does this or is there another method that I need to be using?

Thanks for any help or direction that you can provide.

UPDATE:

I'm looking at triggers and have something like this.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_lastupdate 
    BEFORE INSERT ON tableB
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE tableA SET lastupdate=now() WHERE id=NEW.tableA_id;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm just not sure how to deal with the id in the UPDATE line as it needs to be dynamic. TableB has a column called tableA_id that is the id that I'm after.

Am I going down the right road?

Just updated the code with NEW.tableA_id. Appears to work, is this the best method?

Comment: Well, I'd just use an after update trigger, but I'm used to SQL Server. I assume MySQL supports triggers...

Comment: Why do you have 2 timestamp fields in this case? Just have 1 and join the 2 tables if you ned to query last update time for the table that does not have the timestamp.

Comment: Not sure what joining two tables does. When A updates i don't want the timestamp column in B to update. Just the other way around. 

At the moment I have it working but it is a bit of a hack I'm sure. When I UPDATE table B I do have a relationship setup so I get the id of table A from B and then force an update on table A. I just know there has to be a better solution. I have also not heard of triggers so I'm looking that up now.

Comment: I think I got it..

NEW.tableA_id

Does that look right?